# How to separate comma-split data from 1 field and move into 2 separate fields in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I DO NOT need to create the 2 new fields to move the data to. The fields have already been created. I just need to move the comma-separated data from 1 field into the 2 fields that have already been created

I have 1 column with city and state data. I need to move the data from that 1 column into the 2 columns- one for city and for state.

I need to take the comma-split data from Address1 and place into Address2 and Address3 column.

```
Address1 (column)
Anywhere, USA
```

```
Address2 (column)  Address3 (column)
Anywhere            USA
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may use solution from [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns) to create an UPDATE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (Address1 varchar(100),Address2 varchar(100),Address3 varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #test (Address1) VALUES ('Anywhere, USA')
INSERT INTO #test (Address1) VALUES ('Anywhere')

UPDATE #test set
Address2 = Substring(Address1 , 1,Charindex(',', Address1)-1),
Address3 = Substring(Address1 , Charindex(',', Address1 )+1, LEN(Address1))
WHERE Address1 LIKE '%,%'

SELECT * FROM #test
DROP TABLE #test
```

Comment: I am getting the follwing error message:Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Probably some of your data do not have any commas, I updated the code.

Comment: Thank you, Piotr. I was able to split the data thanks to the coding you provided.